# Unable to install ruby with RVM due to errors on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rvm

I am new to ruby and am trying to reinstall ruby versions on my machine using RVM.

So far each installation fails. The terminal output is:

```
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.3 - #downloading ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.3 - #extracting ruby-2.3.3 to /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.3..|
ruby-2.3.3 - #applying patch /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/patches/ruby/ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch.
ruby-2.3.3 - #applying patch /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.3/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.3.3 - #configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.3.3 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.3 - #compiling........................................................-
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/log/1549931271_ruby-2.3.3/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

the relevant parts of the log seem to be as follows:

```
./ossl_pkey.h:44:23: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                      ^
./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:60: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)

./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:103: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                                                                      ^
In file included from ossl_pkey_rsa.c:12:
In file included from ./ossl.h:236:
./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
#if HAVE_BN_GENCB
    ^
./ossl_pkey.h:44:23: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                      ^
./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:60: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                           ^
./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:103: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                                                                      ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:80:42: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
#if defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) && HAVE_BN_GENCB
                                         ^
./ossl_pkey.h:44:23: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                      ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:80:42: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:60: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                           ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:80:42: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:103: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                                                                      ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:101:42: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
#if defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) && HAVE_BN_GENCB
                                         ^
./ossl_pkey.h:44:23: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                      ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:101:42: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:60: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                           ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:101:42: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./ossl_pkey.h:44:103: note: expanded from macro 'HAVE_BN_GENCB'
#define HAVE_BN_GENCB defined(HAVE_RSA_GENERATE_KEY_EX) || defined(HAVE_DH_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX) || defined(HAVE_DSA_GENERATE_PARAMETERS_EX)
                                                                                                      ^
3 warnings generated.
3 warnings generated.
compiling ossl_pkcs12.c
compiling ossl_pkey_dsa.c
9 warnings generated.
compiling ossl_digest.c
In file included from ossl_pkcs12.c:5:
In file included from ./ossl.h:236:
./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: In file included from ossl_pkey_dsa.c:12:
In file included from ./ossl.h:236:
./ossl_pkey.h:45:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
warning#if HAVE_BN_GENCB
```

I have tried to update rvm and even remove the rubies and openssl and reinstall them. But this error keeps on happening. Could someone please advise me on what to do?

Comment: Is 2.3.3 supported on macOS 10.14? That may not be the case as I know major changes in OpenSSL have broken a lot of older Ruby versions. You may want to try [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which can often download pre-built binary versions that come with the necessary dependencies.

Comment: I am not sure sorry, is there a way to check or should I just try a later version, like 2.6.1?

Comment: Unless you've got something preventing you from upgrading it's usually worth going with the latest version. 2.6 is significantly faster than 2.3 in a number of key areas, so you may appreciate the difference. I've seen very few upgrade problems, but as an example if you use the old `mysql` driver or unmaintained gems with compiled extensions you may have problems. Otherwise it's usually quite seamless.

Comment: Ok, will try it and get back to you. Thank you very much!